# If $u=x\cos y$ and $v=x\sin y$, then near $(x_0,y_0)$, with $x_0\neq 0$, then $(x,y)$ can be written as a differentiable function of $(u,v)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, analysis

> Consider the following equations
> $$u = x \cos(y)\ \ \text{and}\ \ v=x \sin(y)$$
> Show that near to $(x_0,y_0)$, with $x_0\neq 0$, $(x,y)$ can be written as a differentiable function of $(u,v)$.

It's seems simple, but I'm feeling like I'm doing it wrong.

Until now, I have supposed that $u,\ v\ \neq 0$. So I've reached that
\begin{equation}
|x|=\sqrt{u^2+v^2}\ and\ y=arctg(\frac{v}{u}).
\end{equation}

So,
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}=\frac{u}{x}\ and \ \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}=\frac{v}{x}.
\end{equation}

Depending on the value of $x$, we have
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}=\frac{\pm u}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}\ and \ \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}=\frac{\pm v}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}.
\end{equation}

That's all I did and unfortunately I feel it's wrong and it's not the answer. Do you have any tips for me?

Comment: "Differentiable" equation or "differential" equation? Those are two different things

Comment: The problem requires a differentiable function and all I get are these two differential equations.

Comment: You need the two-variable arctan function $\operatorname{atan2}(y,x).$ Beccause your formula doesn’t return the right thing when $u,v<0,$ and doesn’t allows $u=0.$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2

Comment: Have you looked at polar coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the use of the word "near", which, in more precise terms means in some (punctured) open ball around $(x_0,y_0)$, ie, in $B((x_0,y_0),\epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon\gt 0$. Since $x_0\neq 0$, you can ensure there's a ball centered at $(x_0,y_0)$ such that the sign of the $x$-component of any point in that ball is the same as that of $x_0$. As such $x(u,v)=\sqrt{u^2+v^2}$ or $x(u,v)=-\sqrt{u^2+v^2}$ depending on the sign of $x_0$ but not both, ie, you do not need to use $|x|$ there (also, $|x|$ is incorrect as then $x(u,v)$ is not a function, it will have two possible values for given arguments $u,v$) Showing that it is a differentiable function of $u,v$ for the two cases is an easy check (use the limit definition of derivative).

For $y$, you need the $\operatorname{atan2}(v,u)$ (2-argument arctangent) for reasons Thomas Andrews mentioned.

Comment: I apreciate your reply, thank you!! I realy needed that kind of light about $B((x_0,y_0),\epsilon)$.

Answer (score 2):

You need the [two-variable arctan function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) $\operatorname{atan2}(y,x).$

Your formula doesn’t return the correct angle when $u,v<0,$ and doesn’t allows $u=0.$

The problem is that $\operatorname{atan2}$ can’t be made  continuous on $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{0\}.$ Given any non-zero $(x,y),$ it can be made differentiable in some neighborhood of $(x,y).$

We can, in fact, make it differentiable on $$\mathbb R\setminus\{(-tx,-ty)\mid t\in\mathbb R^{\geq 0}\}$$

Comment: Thank you Thomas! I'll search for the two-variable arctan function  and try again.